# How to convert series of commands into a Vim Function?

Tags: vimscript, vimrc

I currently run a series of commands on any file I am working on to compress the lines. That series is -

```
G:a
PRESS ENTER KEY
.
:g/^./ .,/^$/-1 join
```

So I press `S-g`, `S-:`, `a`, `enter`, `.`, then run that regular expression. This joins my lines.

```
function! CrunchLines()
exec G
exec :
exec  a
exec return
.
:g/^./ .,/^$/-1 join
endfu
com! CRUNCH call CrunchLines()
```

How do you just run vim commands inside of a function?

Comment: Can you explain what does the `G:a<CR>.` does ? because it does nothing in my vim, except to go to the last line ...

Comment: @Nobe4 - Yes, it goes to the last line. Then we insert a blank line at the bottom of the file by pressing enter and the period key. There are TWO <CR> one after the a and then again to insert the space.

Comment: OK, can you add this detail into your question, and maybe use the `<S-g>` notation, or the <kbd>.</kbd> one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run a command from a vim function you can do so with the normal command :

```
normal! dd
```

This act as `dd` in normal mode.
The `!` prevent using user mapping, to you get the basic vim functionalities.

Now to compress your file you can go to the last line with `G` and then joins every lines with your expression.

So the function could be :

```
function! Crunch() abort
  normal! G
  g/^./ .,/^$/-1 join
endfunction
```

You can also use the `J` key that joins the lines like so :

```
function! Crunch() abort
  normal! ggVGJ
endfunction
```

Decomposing :

```
gg  : go to first line
V   : start a visual line selection
G   : go to last line
J   : join the selection
```

Answer (score 1):

My exact method was -

```
" Crunch multi line text into single line
" Useful for moving text from .tex to web services
function! Crunch() abort
    normal! G
    normal! o
    g/^./ .,/^$/-1 join
endfunction
com! CRUNCH call Crunch()
```

This allows me to crunch multi line files correctly.